# Delete listbox item that using DataSource that come from mdb(MS ACCESS)

Tags: c#, ms-access, listbox, datasource

I created a winform program and have a listbox and delete button in my form. My listbox is using a datasource/databinding that come from .mdb (Microsoft Access) file. Here is the delete button code I use now:

```
private void deletepcsetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to delete PC No " + listBox1.SelectedItem + "?", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        PCNo selectedPCNo = (PCNo)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedPCNo != null)
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM ClientListing WHERE PCNO = " + listBox1.SelectedItem + "", GetConnection());
            _pcno.Remove(selectedPCNo);
        }
        GetConnection().Close();
    }
}
```

Ignore about the message box, the code above successful delete the item from my listbox but not from the database (mdb), so this thing gives me a problem because after reopen the form I notice the item that has been deleted before is still there (its just delete from listbox but not mdb).

I also have tried to change the delete command from `" + listBox1.SelectedItem + "` to `"selectedPCNo"` but it didn't work, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the Command Executor ...?

just add the below line and try the same ....

```
MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedItem); //Check whether the Selected Item Rendered or NOT

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM ClientListing WHERE PCNO = " + listBox1.SelectedItem + "", GetConnection());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() // it Executes the query...
_pcno.Remove(selectedPCNo);
```

Comment: arghh..i was forgot about the executor..thank for reminding me..anyway now its popup an error which is

"No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: @ZulfakarZukri Display a Message box and confirm that the selected item was Correctly rendered or not... MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedItem)... and try the same...

Comment: Can you list me what are the items that listed in your ListBox...? Also in Database Table the field PCNO have what values... ?

Comment: the problem has solve, i just change "listBox1.SelectedItem" to "pcno.Text" which is the value from textbox while binding the data into that textbox(anyway i set the textbox properties to disable before they push the edit button..anyway thanks for reminding me about the executor..cheers

Comment: the item on the listbox is a number which come from mdb file field PCNO and the value is 1,2,3, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have listBox1.SelectedItem returns the correct value, have you tried with the SelectedValue instead?

Comment: im was thinking the value selected is not correct as the message box showing like this.. "Are you sure want to delete PC No Platinum_Server.PCNo?"